# How to change manpage pager

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, manpage, pager, more

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 with GNOME 3.16 and my current default pager for `man` is `less` (I think), but I would like to change it to something else like `more`, does anyone know how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the environment variable `MANPAGER`

```
export MANPAGER=more
```

e.g. in your `~/.profile` or systemwide in `/etc/environment`

Thus only is affected the `man` command.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest change would be to configure it by placing in `~/.manpath`:

> DEFINE pager more

Alternatively, you can set the environment variable `MANPAGER` to the program you want to use, as [noted by A.B.](https://askubuntu.com/a/679058/294315) Or if you generally prefer less to more, you can also set it on `PAGER`, which is also honored by other programs, like git.

[man](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/man-db) searchs a pager by:

- using the program set in $MANPAGER, else…
- using the program set in $PAGER, else…
- using the `pager` setting from the configuration (first user, then global) else…
- using the default pager set in the ./configure step else…
- using the `cat` setting from configuration (first user, then global) else…
- using `cat`

Comment: @A.B. are you sure you don't have MANPAGER set? You may use `env -i TERM=$TERM PAGER=mypager man man` for testing

Comment: I will check it again :)

Comment: PAGER isn't ignored, sorry =)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the given answers one can change the Ubuntu default pager by running

```sh
sudo update-alternatives --config pager
```

This will list a couple of pagers and ask to choose one.
This will change the default pager for `man` and for other programs too.